# Binding Troubles ViewModel with Command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a binding problem.
Maybe I didn't see it.

XAML File

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="itemsControlTiles" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCatalogLightList}" Margin="10">
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         FlowDirection="LeftToRight" IsItemsHost="true">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Controls:Tile Title="{Binding Name}"
                           Margin="3"
                           Background="{Binding Background}"
                           Style="{StaticResource PrdukteTileStyle}" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource productsTileViewModel}, Path=DoSomethingCommand}" 
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding ID,ElementName= ProductCatalogLightList}" />

                            </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Controls:Tile>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

So my Problem is the CommandParameter Binding.

My ModelView looks like that

```
public class Product_Catalog_Light
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.Brush Background { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsTileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ObservableCollection<Product_Catalog_Light> _product_Catalog_LightList;
    public ProductsTileViewModel()
    {
        ProductCatalogLightList = new ObservableCollection<Product_Catalog_Light>();
    }
  ......
    public ObservableCollection<Product_Catalog_Light> ProductCatalogLightList
    {
        get { return _product_Catalog_LightList; }
        set
        {
            _product_Catalog_LightList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductCatalogLightList");
        }
    }

}

public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _doSomethingCommand ??
                   (_doSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand<int>(ExecuteDoSomethingWithItem));
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand<int> _doSomethingCommand;


    private void ExecuteDoSomethingWithItem(int db_ID )
    {
        // Do something wir the _id
        int i = 5;
    }
```

I'm getting an error message that says it can't find the binding source.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=ProductCatalogLightList'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ID; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'InvokeCommandAction' (HashCode=11254959); target property is
>   'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an element named ProductCatalogLightList, also your datacontext in the trigger is already a Product_Catalog_Light so just do this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ID}"
```

ElementName is used when binding to a property of a control in your xaml, for example if you named your Control:Tile you could bind to its Title property

Comment: Oh yes...
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Ebc: Try using [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It lets you tranverse the visual tree to see/change properties. It may also help you to se the active DataContext of a control.